# jQuery confirmation not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, alert, confirm

I'm trying to create a basic confirmation box which prompts users with a simple confirm/cancel when they click on a link.

This is working fine in FF and IE, however Chrome just seems to ignore it.

Can anyone see why this might not be working?

```
//Confirm Duplication        
$("a[href*=duplicate]").click(function(event){         
   var answer = confirm("Duplicate?")     
   if(!answer){
      event.preventDefault();    
   }
 });
```

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to have a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060345/click-event-fires-in-ie-firefox-but-chrome-is-dropping-the-event-assignment

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a similar issue by changing the initial jquery call from

```
$().ready(function()
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function()
```