# Return confirm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, confirm

I have problem with return confirm in Chrome. In Firefox it is ok.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var result = confirm('Really?');

    if(result) {
        console.log('Do something');
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What problem do you have with it in Chrome?

Comment: 8 question and 0% accept ratio.... u need to work on that first...:)

Comment: [jQuery confirmation not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555089/jquery-confirmation-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: Wild speculation: Your problem is that you have the Chrome developer tools set to clear the `console.log` history when the page changes or is reloaded.

Comment: `function {` is a syntax error btw (type in the post I assume).

Comment: Having a typo in the code in the post means that the code wasn't copy/pasted from the code that "is OK" in Firefox, so there is a not insignificant chance that whatever causes the problem in Chrome hasn't been included in the retyped code either. Please *construct a minimal test case, **test** that it demonstrates the working and not-working cases, then **copy/paste** it* (a link to live test case is also appreciated).

Comment: Let's give the guy some credit. Seems like a legit question to me: fixing the typo, `function() {` instead of `function {`, the script works both in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. I think @kooiinc answer is right, both fixing the typo and returning something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return something from `beforeunload`.

The `confirm` will be ignored

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm() and
>   window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.

[see **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Date will be lost: are you sure?'; //<= here
}
```

If you don't return something, the actions within the handler function are executed before the page unloads.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dialogs (in some browsers) when a user is trying to leave the page. Otherwise you could just put a constant stream of alerts.