# Simulate a click on 'a' tag in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a link ('a' tag).
I'm trying to click it using JavaScript.
While `.click();` does well in Firefox and IE but it fails in Chrome.
(Chrome says the object does not have the click method).

Triggering the 'onclick' or redirecting to the 'href' won't do the job.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Preferably I wouldn't get an entire library just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

should work in chrome

Answer (score 2):

In non-IE-browsers use [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 1):

I understand you do not want a library but this one's footprint is quite small, you can use [event.simulate](http://code.google.com/p/protolicious/source/browse/trunk/src/event.simulate.js) for this. it is a PrototypeJS lib, but i'm sure the porting would be very easy.

To use it in prototype you would call:

```
$('my_anchor').simulate('click');
```

It works cross-browser with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to just use the library's method ... in the case of mootools, .fireEvent('click') is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the referenced post there the author have the the same problem.
He solves it by running a script in the onLoad callback;

```
<body onLoad="DefaultButtonFix()">
```

Refernece: [Click event fires in IE/Firefox, but Chrome is dropping the event assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060345/click-event-fires-in-ie-firefox-but-chrome-is-dropping-the-event-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
function dispatchEvent(el, e)
{
    // console.log("dispatching");

    if ("createEvent" in document)
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(e, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else
    {
        el.fireEvent("on" + e);
    }

}

dispatchEvent(document.getElementById("mylink"), "click");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know jQuery simply create an anonymous function and listen for the onclick event. You will need to specify a class or id for you href,

e.g.
HTML :

```
<a href='' id='clickMe'>Click here</a>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function() {  
  $("#clickMe").click(function() {
    ... the action you wish to perform ...
  }) 
})
```

Hope this helps.
Dave

Comment: this only listens for a click event, the op wants to 'simulate' a click.

Comment: Valid point, I should have read the op message more thoroughly!