# Cannot trigger a click from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a similar post about this but it was closed for being too localized. After some research and testing, I think I found the source of the problem, and this question should be better explained and hopefully more helpful.

Using XMLHttpRequest I need to go to a page, simulate a mouse click, then get some contents. Here is the code I wrote:

```
var sendToLog;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/newsfeed-simulator', true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) 
  {

    var event = xhr.response.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
xhr.response.getElementById("simulate-button").dispatchEvent(event);

    $(xhr.response).ready(function() 
    {
        console.log(xhr.response.body);
        sendToLog = xhr.response.getElementsByClassName("story-score");
    });

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({writeToLog: sendToLog});  

}
}

xhr.send();
```

Problem is click event does not work. Tried it also `xhr.response.getElementById("simulate-button").click();` to no avail.

Not sure what is the problem? It should be a straight forward afair: **go to a page, wait for it to load, click a button, wait for it to load again, and then get contents from DOM.**

Any help would be appreciated it.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT** removed second onload, and added xhr.response. Now it prints the DOM without the mouse click to the console. Still not what I needed but maybe it is a step in the right direction

**EDIT2**: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801570/simulate-a-click-on-a-tag-in-chrome) post and others, it's better not to use click since it only works in IE. So I edited my code but till doesn't work...bummer

**EDIT3** As Fabien Quatravaux, the problem here is that the ajax request response is not loaded into the current DOM, so I cannot call out the event (well I can but it won't do anything). So the question is how can I using xmlhttprequest, go to a page using, fire an event and then get the resulting DOM?? Thank you again Fabien for pointing this out.

Comment: Are you trying to fire an event on the ajax response body, as if it was loaded into the DOM ? Stop me if I'm wrong, but the ajax request response is not loaded into the current DOM, so you cannot execute scripts on it, event if it has been parsed as a document. Take a look at the [XMLHttpRequest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#document-response-entity-body) : point 5-4 says "with scripting disabled";

Comment: Wow I think you are correct, thanks for clarifying this!! Do you know if a way go to a page using xmlhttprequest, fire an event and then get the resulting DOM? My way of doing this is clearly not the correct one.

Comment: I think you are not looking into the right direction. You are trying to use a peace of code (the javascript that lives on this html page you are pointing to) that you do not control and that has not been written to do want you want. Instead, you should figure out what this button (or event) is doing, and just do the same. Perhaps the button you want to click is sending a request to a server, perhaps it is just unhiding an HTML node already present on the page, ... Look at the event handler code of that page and try to do the same (take care to cross domain issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fabien Quatravaux, the problem here is that the ajax request response is **NOT** loaded into the current DOM, so I cannot call out the event. 
I solved this problem by just opening a new tab and going to that page directly. The draw back to this solution is that the user can see this tab, but at least it works.

Thanks all for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the XmlHttpRequest has a **response** property. I think you might take the responseText and manipulate the DOM (ie add a button)-- then you can click the button and make another XmlHttpRequest.

**Edit:**

I stand corrected, I see it does have one-- I've just never used it in this way.

I think the bigger issue is that assuming that you get back a document in the response and you find a button and cause the click event, then what is supposed to happen. I don't think you have anything wired up to the click event.

I also agree with other post, that you should definitely be using jQuery. Seems like you are just attempting to call successive AJAX requests, no?

Comment: After simulating a click, some elements will be added to the page (i.e. the DOM will change). One of those elements is: 
`<div class="story-score">
     //some score
 </div>`, I have to get that score and print it to the console.

I am still new to javascript. Its my first time I program with it, so I am still learning stuff, that's why I didn't use AJAX. 
Anyways yes, I am trying to call two ajaxs: one to go to a page, and one to simulate a mouse click.

Comment: @Shane - I think if you're first learning JavaScript- XHR (or AJAX) requests can be a bit complicated. So you want to do an AJAX request when the page loads and second one when the first ajax request returns? I think I would add what you get back to ajax request to the DOM of the calling page-- then you can simulate the button click, and call another AJAX request.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough (as said, i am still new to all of this). My xhr request works fine and I can simulate a mouse click perfectly. Problem is that after simulating a click I cannot find the what I need in the DOM. 
Maybe here I need to add the response to the to the DOM (as you suggested) but I am not sure how to do it. Or maybe I do not need to do that, and the problem is that I called my function before everything got loaded (thats why I added my second onload).

Answer (score -1):

modify xhr.response.getElementById("simulate-button").click(); to document.getElementById("simulate-button").click();

remove $(xhr.response).ready function

modify sendToLog = xhr.response.getElementsByClassName("story-score"); to
sendToLog = document.getElementsByClassName("story-score");

Comment: This does not work. It will just look for "simulate-button" in the original document and return and error since it could not find it. I want to do all these operations on the document I got from the XMLHttpRequest and not the original document. That's the whole reason for XHR.


With that said, thank you for answering. If you have any ideas don't hesitate to post it. :)

Comment: This is not the correct format for entering code or answering questions.